# Disabling Crostab page break

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

Background:

I have a report with a large dataset on a crosstab element. The report will only cater to spreadsheet format so the width of the report will not matter.

I have tried setting the **Ignore Pagination** property to true. **Split Type** to **prevent** but some of the data still breaks and moves on the bottom of the sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I was using iReport 3.7.4 and there was a bug in the UI. Apparently the crostabs property **ignoreWidth="true"** was showing as ticked in the UI but it was actually missing from the xml. You can locate this property in the crosstab tag as shown below:

```
<crosstab ignoreWidth="true">
     ... 
</crosstab>
```